# Why does C allow us to treat a 2D array as 1D?

Tags: c, pointers

Here, I am able to access the elements of a 2D array using only one loop. So, it seems that I don't need to teat this array as 2D.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>

main()
{
    int array[][3] = {11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99};

    int * pArr = &array;
    int i=0;

    printf("Addr\tValue\n");
    for(i=0 ; i<9 ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t%d\n", &pArr[i], pArr[i]);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

### Output

```
Addr    Value
2358344 11
2358348 22
2358352 33
2358356 44
2358360 55
2358364 66
2358368 77
2358372 88
2358376 99
```

Why does C allow us to do this?

[image]

Comment: http://www.google.com.ng/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=How+can+I+use+a+%22pointer+to%22+a+%222D+array%22%3F

Comment: If you turn on compiler warnings, you'll find that your code isn't valid.

Comment: I have coded this on VC++2008Express. And I found no error and not even any message from the debug library.

Comment: @Saqib: Like I said, turn on compiler warnings.  (Something like Project->Properties->C/C++->General->Warning Level.)

Comment: I have set the warning level to Level-4. Nothing happened. Now what?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean.  Here is one possible interpretation:

```
int x[5][10];  // 2D array
int (*p)[5][10] = &x;  // Pointer to 2D array

(*p)[3][2] = 1;  // Dereferencing pointer
```

And here is another:

```
int x[5*10];  // 1D array
int *p = x;   // Pointer to first element of array

p[3*10+2] = 1;  // Dereferencing pointer
```

And here is another:

```
int **p;    // Pointer to pointer
p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * 5);  // Create array of pointers
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    p[i] = malloc(sizeof(p[i]) * 10);  // Create array of ints
}

p[3][2] = 1;  // Dereferencing pointer

...

// Clearup
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    free(p[i]);
}
free(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't; a pointer only tells you where to look, not what the target is.

Take this example 2D array:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 0 1 2
```

This will be represented in the memory as

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2
```

Only if you know that this is an `int[3][4]` you can get the array again. C does not store whether it's an `int[2][6]` or `int[3][4]`.

**If** you know the dimensions of the array, it becomes easy, since you can simply assign it.

Comment: There's no information at runtime, but that doesn't mean you can't do size-specific stuff.  See my answer.

Comment: Also, you can't write `int arry[3][4] = pointer;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int **pointer;
```

pointer holds the address of the first element of a collecton of `int *` elements.

That first element is an `int *` pointer.

That element may point to an actual `int`.

So, pointer points to the first element of a collection of pointers, of which the first element points to an int. If you add 1 to `pointer`, you get the next pointer that may point to an int

This is what "2D" means in C pointer arithmetics.

Comment: Not really.  It is possible to have a true 2D array (e.g. `int x[3][4]`), which is completely different to a pointer-to-pointer.